# Test MariaDB credentials in WIX Installer UI

Tags: windows, wix, mariadb

I created a WIX installer for a web application. It gets the credentials for the MariaDB connection that the application uses. Now I would like to give the user the opportunity to test the credentials before continuing the installation. This should prevent common mistakes and save time.

My problem is now that I can't find a way to test the connection before I installed any MariaDB connector. I can't find any example although I think this should be a common need. Has anybode done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It is not a perfect solution. But it works and may help others:

## Required binaries

I packed the required libraries for MariaDB into a self-extracting zip file with 7zip. A CustomAction triggered from UI starts the executable and extracts the MariaDB client files:

```xml
<Binary Id="mariadb_client_10.1_exe" SourceFile="resources\MariaDB 10.1.exe" />
<CustomAction Id="ExtractMariadbClient" BinaryKey="mariadb_client_10.1_exe" ExeCommand="-o./ -y" Execute="immediate" />
```

The extraction is triggered after welcome dialog:

```xml
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="ExtractMariadbClient" Order="1">1</Publish>
```

## Validation

This is my UI that collects the credentials:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="MariaDBDialog" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.InstallDirDlg_Title)">
                <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" />
                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.MariaDBDlgDescription)" />
                <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.MariaDBDlgTitle)" />
                <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgBannerBitmap)" />
                <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />

                <Control Id="HostLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="65" Width="60" Height="18" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Host" />
                <Control Id="Host" Type="Edit" X="80" Y="60" Width="260" Height="18" Property="MARIADB_HOSTNAME" Indirect="no" />
                <Control Id="PortLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="85" Width="60" Height="18" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Port" />
                <Control Id="Port" Type="Edit" X="80" Y="80" Width="260" Height="18" Property="MARIADB_PORT" Indirect="no" />
                <Control Id="UserLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="105" Width="60" Height="18" NoPrefix="yes" Text="User" />
                <Control Id="User" Type="Edit" X="80" Y="100" Width="260" Height="18" Property="MARIADB_USER" Indirect="no" />
                <Control Id="PasswordLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="125" Width="60" Height="18" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Password" />
                <Control Id="Password" Type="Edit" X="80" Y="120" Width="260" Height="18" Property="MARIADB_PASSWORD" Indirect="no" Password="yes" />
                <Control Id="DatabaseLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="145" Width="60" Height="18" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Database" />
                <Control Id="Database" Type="Edit" X="80" Y="140" Width="260" Height="18" Property="MARIADB_DATABASE" Indirect="no" />

                <Control Type="PushButton" Id="TestConnection" Width="93" Height="17" X="80" Y="243" Text="Test Connection">
                    <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="TestDatabaseConnection" Order="1">1</Publish>
                </Control>
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

There is a button to test the connection. And the script is also triggered when user clicks next:

```xml
<Publish Dialog="MariaDBDialog" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="TestDatabaseConnection" Order="1">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="MariaDBDialog" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="NetworkDlg" Order="2">DATABASE_CONNECTION_VALID="1"</Publish>
```

You see that *DATABASE_CONNECTION_VALID* needs to be *1* in order to continue.

The whole validation magic is done in another CustomAction with VBScript:

```xml
<Binary Id="testDatabaseConnection" SourceFile="resources\testDatabaseConnection.vbs" />
<CustomAction Id="TestDatabaseConnection" BinaryKey="testDatabaseConnection" VBScriptCall="testDatabaseConnection" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore">1</CustomAction>
```

```
Function testDatabaseConnection()
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    dim hostname
    hostname = Session.Property("MARIADB_HOSTNAME")
    dim port
    port = Session.Property("MARIADB_PORT")
    dim user
    user = Session.Property("MARIADB_USER")
    dim password
    password = Session.Property("MARIADB_PASSWORD")
    dim database
    database = Session.Property("MARIADB_DATABASE")
    dim currDir
    currDir = Session.Property("CURRENTDIRECTORY")
    dim command

    if Len(password) = 0 then
        command = currDir & "/MariaDB_client_10.1/bin/mysql.exe -h " & hostname & " --port " & port & " -u " & user & " -e ""show databases;"""
    else
        command = currDir & "/MariaDB_client_10.1/bin/mysql.exe -h " & hostname & " --port " & port & " -u " & user & " -p" & password & " -e ""show databases;"""
    end if
    dim ret
    Set ret = objShell.Exec(command)
    execStdOut = ret.StdOut.ReadAll()
    execStdErr = ret.StdErr.ReadAll()

    if (instr(1, execStdOut, vbCrLf & database & vbCrLf) > 0) then
        MsgBox "MariaDB ist erreichbar und die Datenbank " & database & " ist vorhanden.", vbInformation, "Verbindungstest"
        Session.Property("DATABASE_CONNECTION_VALID") = "1"
    elseIf (Len(execStdErr) > 0) then
        MsgBox "Verbindung zur MariaDB konnte nicht hergestellt werden. Fehlermeldung: " & execStdErr, vbCritical, "Verbindungstest"
        Session.Property("DATABASE_CONNECTION_VALID") = "0"
    else
        MsgBox "Verbindung zur MariaDB erfolgreich, aber Datenbank ist nicht vorhanden. Folgende Datenbanken existieren:" & vbCrLf & execStdOut, vbCritical, "Verbindungstest"
        Session.Property("DATABASE_CONNECTION_VALID") = "0"
    end if
End Function
```

Hope it helps someone else and saves some time.